# ggplot2 trying to specify number of columns of legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am having a difficult understanding why this code works and doesn't work. I want a plot by group + specify the number of columns of my legend. Basically, the only way I can get this to work is to specify both a fill and a colour variable in the aesthetic. It seems like fill allows me to change the columns and colour changes colors of the lines, but this feels a bit kludgy. Does anyone have a good understanding of the logic here, or a better way to accomplish this goal? I’ll accept a base plot answer!

My example code is below:

```
# ~ Library ~ #
require(ggplot2)

# Generate example data 
x=1:10
y=10:1
data = data.frame(x_data=rep(1:10,2),
                  y_data=c(x,y),
                  group=c(rep('A',length(x)),rep('B',length(y))))

# ~ Plot data ~ #

# Only this works
plot = ggplot(data,aes(x=x_data,y=y_data,fill=group,colour=group)) + geom_line()
plot = plot + guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

[image: Correct Plot]

```
# This doesn't work
plot = ggplot(data,aes(x=x_data,y=y_data,fill=group)) + geom_line()
plot = plot + guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
plot
```

[image]

```
# Neither does this
plot = ggplot(data,aes(x=x_data,y=y_data,colour=group)) + geom_line()
plot = plot + guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
plot
```

[image]

As suggested by h-1, this works

```
#This works
plot = ggplot(data,aes(x=x_data,y=y_data,fill=group)) + geom_line()
plot = plot + guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
plot
```

[image]

Comment: `plot + guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol = 2))` will work for the last plot.  You need to use the same argument you used in `aes()`, i.e. `colour` not `fill`.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any sense why that is?

Comment: Lines don't have a `fill` aesthetic so `fill=group` won't do anything to the lines. `fill` and `colour` both affect the colours you see but in different ways, you need to make sure you're using the right one.

Comment: Yeah, what Marius said, fill isn't really doing anything for you. There's no geom that uses it.

Comment: The real issue here is confusion regarding `fill` versus `color`. If you remove `fill = group` in the first example and specify `color` in `guides()` instead of `fill`, it will work. Similarly in the last example you use `color` for the geom but `fill` in `guides()`.

Comment: I see, so colour = outline (in this case a line is simply an outline), as I don't have any geoms that have an interior, fill does nothing?

Comment: Right. If you read `?geom_line` there's an Aesthetics section which tells you what you can put inside `aes()` for that geom.